# Minikube local cluster is not starting

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-toolbox

I have windows 10 Home single Language.
I have install kubectl and minikube. Also I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows.

while executing  `minikube start --kubernetes-version=1.17.0` command I am getting bellow error:

```
* minikube v1.8.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0.18363 Build 18363
* Automatically selected the hyperv driver
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=3000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 63 [running]:
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.hypervAvailable(0xc000035a10, 0xc00062b0a8)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/medyagh/machine@v0.16.4/drivers/hyperv/powershell.go:64 +0x105
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.(*Driver).PreCreateCheck(0xc0006f64e0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/medyagh/machine@v0.16.4/drivers/hyperv/hyperv.go:171 +0x3b
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.(*LocalClient).Create(0xc0000455c0, 0xc0006f6540, 0xc000604008, 0x0)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/client.go:227 +0x344
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost.func2(0x1de8600, 0xc0000455c0, 0xc0006f6540, 0xc000686370, 0xc0000b2540)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:164 +0x42
created by k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:163 +0x10e
```

Comment: What is the go version?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2181#issuecomment-344916328) or [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2954) or [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4374#issuecomment-611863890) solve your issue?

Comment: Part of the requirements of HyperV is Windows 10 Enterprise, Pro, or Education. 
I would upgrade the windows to pro before trying to use the hyper-V Hypervisor or try to install VirtualBox and set `--vm-driver=virtualbox`.

Comment: I have to reinstall the docker toolbox...Also, I have to delete .minikube and .virtualbox folder